# SQL Programación de BBDD

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Estoy intentando resolver este ejercicio.

> Crear una función que dados dos números enteros devuelva la
> multiplicación de los mismos, usando solamente la suma.

Lo que tengo es:

```
Delimiter //
    create function Multiplicacion (n1 int, n2 int)
    returns int deterministic
    begin
    declare res int;
    declare sum int;
    while sum <n2 do
        set sum=sum+1;
        set res=res+n1;
    end while;
end;    
//*
```

Pero no se por que me da este error, ni como solucionarlo.

```
*No RETURN found in FUNCTION jardineria.Multiplicacion*
```

He intentado ejecutarlo con diferentes tablas pero me siguen dando el mismo error.

Comment: Tienes que retornar el valor, poniendo algo como esto: `return res;` después de `end while;` y antes de `end;` De todos modos, no se entiende el enunciado de tu ejercicio ni lo que pretendes hacer exactamente en esta función. ¿Qué quiere decir devolver la **multiplicación** usando la **suma**?

Comment: @A.Cedano es un ejercicio tipico para aprender sobre iteraciones (aunque raro para dar con bases de datos)... quiere decir que hay que iterar tantas veces como uno de los operandos (ya que la multiplicacion no es mas que la suma de uno de los valores, segun el otro valor)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Rosa, sobre que base de datos? googleaste el error?

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias por la ayuda. Tomaré en cuenta los consejos para ir mejorando. En cuanto a tus preguntas, sí, las google y al no encontrar una solución me anime a probar a publicarla aquí y no se muy bien a que te refieres con que base de datos ? son unas que nos dan en clase que por lo que he estado investigando algunas son de esta página  https://josejuansanchez.org/bd/ejercicios-consultas-sql/index.html

Comment: claro.. sobre que base de datos estas practicando? la sintaxis de los SP suele ser muy pero muy diferente entre los motores... que base de datos estas usando?

Comment: ya te lo he corregido

Comment: @Rosa no te olvides para que se resuelva la preguntas debes marcas con el ✔ la respuesta que mas te ha ayudado y si es buena de votarla positivamente con ^ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado tu error. Si te fija tu **end** termina en punto y coma debe terminar en // como le dijiste en el delimitador, luego aparte no devuelve ningún **return** por lo que te da error y al final no vuelves a cambiar el el **delimiter a ;**

En tu **`return`** debe devolver **`suma*res`** y eso te dará la multiplicación.

Otro fallo es que llamaste a suma **`sum`** y ***`sum es una función especial`*** y al declarar las variables le puse ***`por defecto el parámetro n1 a suma`*** y **_`el parámetro n2 a rest_`**

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Multiplicacion //
CREATE FUNCTION Multiplicacion (n1 int, n2 int)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE res INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE suma INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE suma < n2 DO
        SET suma=suma+1;
        SET res=res+n1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN res;
    
END //
DELIMITER ;

SELECT Multiplicacion(2,5);
```

**Te dejo un enlace con el funcionamiento :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/43

Comment: Había un par de errores en el código: el ejercicio solicitaba que no se usara la multiplicación, y se estaba usando en el return. Además, el acumulador "res" debe inicializarse a cero, no a n1. Suma debe inicializarse a cero también y avanzar hasta n2.

Comment: vale muchas gracias amigo, he actualizado el enlace de camino